# How can I get with_loader_criteria to apply to multiple models in a query?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy's `with_loader_criteria` along with the `do_orm_execute` hook to update queries to add additional `WHERE` statements before they're executed. This is to replace the old process of using the `before_compile` hook, which has been deprecated in SQLAlchemy 1.4.

My hook handler looks like this

```py
@event.listens_for(Session, "do_orm_execute")
def receive_do_orm_execute(execute_state):
    if execute_state.is_select and not execute_state.is_column_load:
        print(execute_state.statement)
        execute_state.statement = execute_state.statement.options(
            with_loader_criteria(
                Versioned,
                lambda cls: cls.valid_range.contains(datetime.now(timezone.utc)),
                include_aliases=True,
                propagate_to_loaders=True,
            )
        )
        print(execute_state.statement)
```

Here, `Versioned` is a mixin that my models inherit from. My query looks like this

```py
db_session.query(A, B).join(B, A.id == B.a_id)
```

This produces the two queries below (from the `print` statements in the handler).

```sql
-- Original query
SELECT
    a.id AS a_id,
    a.valid_range AS a_valid_range,
    b.id AS b_id,
    b.a_id AS b_a_id,
    b.valid_range AS b_valid_range
FROM
    a
JOIN
    b
ON
    a.id = b.a_id

-- Modified query after with_loader_criteria runs
SELECT
    a.id AS a_id,
    a.valid_range AS a_valid_range,
    b.id AS b_id,
    b.a_id AS b_a_id,
    b.valid_range AS b_valid_range
FROM
    a
JOIN
    b
ON
    a.id = b.a_id
WHERE
    a.valid_range @> :current_datetime_1
```

I was hoping that since both `A` and `B` inherit from `Versioned`, that both would get an updated `WHERE` clause. Instead only `A` is getting one. Is there way to make sure both are updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this, which is more or less what I had when I was using `before_compile`. I couldn't get `with_loader_criteria` to work for multiple models.

```py
@event.listens_for(Session, "do_orm_execute")
def receive_do_orm_execute(execute_state):
    if execute_state.is_select and not execute_state.is_column_load:
        for ent in execute_state.statement.column_descriptions:
            entity = ent["entity"]

            if entity is None:
                continue

            insp = inspect(entity)
            mapper = getattr(insp, "mapper", None)

            if mapper and issubclass(mapper.class_, Versioned):
                execute_state.statement = execute_state.statement.filter(
                    entity.valid_range.contains(datetime.now(timezone.utc))
                )
```